# How to place progress bar at the top of cardview?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-progressbar, mdc-components

I am placing the progressBar in the cardView at the top with the following code:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:translationZ="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/keyline_2"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:text="Forgot Password ?"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/signIn" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/color_secondary"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="?colorOnSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputPassword" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputPassword"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputEmail"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputEmail"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rel">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextMail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

So. I have tried doing this.. But result is as follows -
[image: Current Situation]

I would like to place it to the extreme top of the cardview like this. It belongs to the google app.
[image: Google App Progress Bar]
Can anyone help me regarding this. I have tried coordinator layout, constraint layout, relative layout, etc. I also tried to change the gravity of the progressBar. It didn't work. Please help.

Comment: wrap your cardview under a view group like linear layout and place a progress bar on top.

Comment: But the progressBar will not be trimmed with rounded edges .. like example from google app

Comment: you will need to customize the progressBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Activity.xml**

  ```
  <LinearLayout>
  ...
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/cv_bg_input_text"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
      app:cardElevation="5dp">

      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editText2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
              android:background="@null"
              android:inputType="textPersonName"
              android:text="Name" />

          <ProgressBar
              android:id="@+id/progressBar"
              style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
              android:indeterminate="true"
              android:scaleY="4" />
      </FrameLayout>

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
  ...
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- Create **cv_bg_input_text.xml** in Drawable

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <stroke android:color="#10000000" android:width="1dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#fff"/>
  </shape>
  ```
- **Result**

[image: Result]

Now for your case just change:

- `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to `android:layout_gravity="top"`
- `android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"` `android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"`

in `<ProgressBar>`:

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your response. I am trying it as fast as I can. If it works I will accept your answer. Have a great day :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped you :)